# WebClient.DownloadString(), URL with ./

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web, httpwebrequest, webclient

I'm having a problem with webclient.downloadstring with links that have ./ in url.

It automatically changes the url as follows:

**Correct URL**
https://in.gov.br/web/dou/-/extrato-de-contrato-n-348/2021-uasg-153290-fac.odontol./ufmg-351093742

**Wrong URL**
https://in.gov.br/web/dou/-/extrato-de-contrato-n-348/2021-uasg-153290-fac.odontol/ufmg-351093742

I've tried everything and I can't find a solution.

Original code:

```
                    WebClient oWebClient;

                    try
                    {
                        oWebClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

                        Uri u = new Uri("https://in.gov.br/web/dou/-/extrato-de-contrato-n-348/2021-uasg-153290-fac.odontol./ufmg-351093742");

                        html = oWebClient.DownloadString(u);                           

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think it's changing it? Maybe show us your actual code?

Comment: Im just doing this:

string html = oWebClient.DownloadString("https://in.gov.br/web/dou/-/extrato-de-contrato-n-348/2021-uasg-153290-fac.odontol./ufmg-351093742");


when I make this request I see in fiddler that it changes the url:

GET https://in.gov.br/en/web/dou/-/extrato-de-contrato-n-348/2021-uasg-153290-fac.odontol/ufmg-351093742 HTTP/1.1
Host: in.gov.br

Comment: You need to show us you REAL code because what you show here, I cannot replicate.

Comment: I post the original code

Comment: Don't post the code in an answer, put it in THIS question

Comment: posted original code in original question

Comment: Maybe Fiddler is showing it wrong then? Is the HTML you download different from what you expected?

Comment: Yes, the html is different than expected. :(

Comment: look the url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlYYs.png its changes './' to '/'

Comment: Yes, but I cannot see the same thing happening here. Are you 100% sure that `.` in the URL is an actual period (i.e. ASCII 2E)?

Comment: Yes i tried use: %2E 
instead . and gets the same problem

Comment: Have you found a solution to the problem?